does the abstract, summary, background sections matter to the claims
There is a specific section called "Detail Description", where detailed embodiments are disclosed.
I know that this section supports the claims.
But what about the other sections of a patent application, such as the abstract, summary, background?
Can these sections limit the claims, or have any impact at all on the claims?


Can these sections limit the claims, or have any impact at all on the claims?

Just as these other sections can be used to support claims, they can also be used to limit claims in certain circumstances.
Sometimes even the title of the patent can be used to limit claims:
https://www.obwb.com/newsletter/patent-title-is-intrinsic-evidence-for-claim-interpretation
